# Unexpectedly Closed Application After Integration Parse.com

Tags: android, permissions, parse-platform, push

There was no problem while running my little android application. I integrated my application new feature. I am using real time push notification with using ready script by www.parse.com . There is no problem while running but when i closed screen and reopen .There is an error. Your application closed unexpectedly. I dont know why and there is no log.

I am using this code in my main activity before oncreate

```
Parse.initialize(this, "XXX", "YYY");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.islamiceducationquestions.v1"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="8.0.1">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.islamiceducationquestions.v1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.islamiceducationquestions.v1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
    -->
    <category android:name="com.islamiceducationquestions.v1" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2844)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:583)
at com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext(Parse.java:191)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getContext(ManifestInfo.java:241)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageManager(ManifestInfo.java:249)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageInfo(ManifestInfo.java:272)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.deviceSupportsGcm(ManifestInfo.java:357)
at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushType(ManifestInfo.java:129)
at com.parse.PushService.startServiceIfRequired(PushService.java:150)
at com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParseBroadcastReceiver.java:19)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2833)
... 10 more
```

Comment: What does "before oncreate" actually mean?

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here [Android Parse.com Simple ListView Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-listview-tutorial/) you will need to call `Parse.initialize` from Application's onCreate instead of from Activity or Service. do it as:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_KEY);

    }

}
```

Also add `ParseApplication` in `AndroidManifest.xml` as application tag name:

```
 <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name="ParseApplication" 
        ....
```

Comment: If i use like this: when uploading this apk there is an error; <application> there must be just one application

Comment: @Mgnfcnt : don't add new application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` just add `android:name="ParseApplication"` in current application tag

Comment: @Mgnfcnt : make sure you have removed `Parse.initialize(this, "XXX", "YYY");` line from Activity

Comment: Yes ; I removed and also removed unused imports

Comment: @Mgnfcnt: please check mention tutorial in answer maybe help you in solving issue.